# Pulse Audio Not Working With X-Forwarding

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, pulse-audio, xforwarding

I'm using Virtualbox VM's. Both host and VM's are running Red Hat 6. When I open the VM, I am able to hear audio from the VM.

However, there is a need for the windows on the VM to be X-Forwarded to the host. Likewise the audio should also be forwarded. When I do this, audio does not work. I've tried to setting the PULSE_SERVER to the host but that hasn't worked.

Specifically, when I forward the Firefox window to the host, no audio is played and a pop up says I need to install a Pulse Audio plugin. As far as I can tell, there isn't a Pulse Audio plugin and it's an issue with X-forwarding the audio.

Any ideas?